# How can I create a Barcode with its string right below?

Tags: ios, swift

I have used `CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator")` to create a Barcode in ios but that Barcode doesn't display its string below. When I try to add a label (for that string) below the Barcode, there will be a big blank space between them. How can I address this?
ps: I show that Barcode in a webVC.

Comment: Please review [ask]. There are a thousand ways to answer your question... you need to provide a lot more information about your layout and show the code for your current attempt.

Comment: If it helps: You can download a barcode-font with text beneath the barcode. Like Code-128 https://www.idautomation.com/barcode-fonts/

Answer (score 1):

Set the `inputQuietSpace` value on the `CIFilter`, for instance:

```
guard let barcode = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") else { return nil }
barcode.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
barcode.setValue(0, forKey: "inputQuietSpace")
```

Zero will remove all spacing, but you can put another value in here to suit if you still want some of the spacing to be handled by the filter.